# Extend String in C++?

Tags: c++

For a school project, I have to create a template class to hold a string of a certain length (cannot be more or less). Is it possible to extend string in some way so I don't have to recreate a lot of the same member functions?

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<int Len> class FixLengthString {
public:
    FixLengthString(const string&);
private:
    string String;
};

template<int Len> FixLengthString<Len>::FixLengthString(const string& Str) {
    if (Str.length() == Len) {
        String = Str;
    }
}
```

Thanks! I know this is probably easy but I'm still learning.

Comment: What about `std::array<char, Len>`?

Comment: Your code does exactly what you're asking for. The trouble with it is that it doesn't do anything else -- it only **holds** the string. What else is it supposed to do?

Comment: I have to create a Student class which holds, for example, an ID number, which needs to be a 9 character string. I need to be able to display and alter that string. I was hoping there would be some way to inherit these functions from string.

Comment: But wouldn't you would have to replace those functions anyway to make sure the string is not set to the wrong length?

Comment: That's a good point...

Comment: *"I don't have to recreate a lot of the same member functions"* - but that's the point. You are creating independent implementation, so you have to independently implement those methods.